# Android WebView doesnt load certain website

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_m);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {   
                return false;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

above code work fine when loading website like :
google.com
html5test.com
blogspot

and other normal website, but when i try to load url like:

http://sipp.pn-sanggau.go.id/

http://sipp.pn-bandung.go.id/

it doesnt work (not load in my activity), why does this happen?

Comment: I have checked your code and the urls do load.
I did notice it took a few seconds to load, and my internet connection is fast, so if you have a slow connection it might be a problem.

Comment: You are right, turn out it took a while to properly load. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in your code.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() ); 
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```